# How can I migrate MySQL 5.7 running in AWS EC2 box to RDS with MySql 8.0?

Tags: json, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, aws-dms

I have one MySQL running in AWS EC2 box and I want to migrate this to MySql 8.0 in AWS RDS.

To achieve this I launched one RDS with MySQL 8.0 and created desired schema there, after this I created one DMS task with target as RDS and source as MySQL running on EC2 box.

With above approach DMS in inserting null values in columns that are of type JSON.

Comment: Please include more details about what you are doing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you mention, what am I missing? I think I have covered required details.